# TTF fonts not displaying in dynamic SVG

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, svg

I have a file called svg.php which puts some TTF text on a curved path and aligns it center. This file displays the TTF font perfectly when I type in the address localhost/AJAX/svg.php?initials=FOO

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/svg+xml');
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 13.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 14948)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="380px" height="253px" viewBox="0 0 380 253" enable-background="new 0 0 380 253" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
@font-face {
font-family: 'LHF';
src: url('LHF.ttf');
} 
text, textPath {
font-family:LHF;
}
]]></style>

<path id="path1" fill="none" d="M50.333,120.339 c92.778-24.903,185.556-24.903,278.334,0"/>

</defs>

<text x="100" y="500" font-size="100" style="fill:black;" text-anchor="middle"><textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="50%"><?php echo $_GET["initials"]; ?></textPath></text>
</svg>
```

However the TTF font is dropped when I call on the image from another page, like index.php for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("fname").value;
document.getElementById("words").src="svg.php?initials=" + x;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br />

<img src="svg.php" id="words" />

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images must be completely self-contained i.e. everything in one file for [privacy reasons](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747).

If you want the ttf font to work when SVG is used as an image (in an image tag or as a CSS image background) you'll have to base64 encode it and embed it as a data URL in the image.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LHF';
    src: url("data:application/x-font-ttf;base64,[base-encoded font here]");
}
```

Alternatively you might be able to use an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag instead of an `<image>` tag depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the enclosing tag. In the first case (working) you load the svg in the page container, in the second case (non working) you load inside an `<img>` tag.

Remove the  tag and just load it in a plain container  `<div>` or `<object>` or directly in another `<svg>` tag or alternatively, you might want to load it using javascript in the browser. For this later case, I'd recommend you the jquery.svg library.

Comment: The only solution that worked was to Base64 encode the font. Thanks very much for the prompt answers guys!